# "tell application" in XCode

Tags: xcode, applescript

Very very newbie to XCode here, although I used it years ago to do all sorts of things in what they used to call Applescript Studio.

I'm trying to get the Finder to tell me the name of the file dropped on my app:

```
on |application|:theApp openFile:aFile
    display alert "123"
    tell application "Finder"
        set theName to (name of aFile)
    end tell
    display alert theName
end
```

"123" is displayed, but theName is not.  Surmising that my syntax is wrong -- I've taken a look at Scripting Bridge, but this seems to be about making my app be able to respond to apple events from other scripts, which is not what I want.

My apologies for straying into possible off-topic areas with my original post.  I figured that it was better to find somewhere that I can solve my own problems than to have to come running for help every time I need it ;-)

Can someone please help me figure out how to get the Finder to tell me the name of a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aFile` is an NSString, so you can use Cocoa to parse `aFile` itself. You have the full resources of Cocoa at your beck and call; involving the Finder is unnecessary. But you cannot *display* an NSString using AppleScript; you must cast it to an AppleScript string first. So, for example:

```
set lpc to aFile's lastPathComponent()
display alert (lpc as string)
```

If you must use AppleScript to do the parsing (e.g. asking the Finder to do it for you) because you're more comfortable that way, then just say `aFile as string` up front and then go ahead and parse further the resulting AppleScript string. For example:

```
set p to aFile as string
tell application "Finder"
    set f to POSIX file p as alias
    get name of f
    display alert result
end tell
```

However, I think that's a very foolish approach; scripting another app is expensive, while using Cocoa directly is not.

Comment: Thanks, but if "the full resources of Cocoa" leave me having to roll my own parser, I'm not very impressed! :-)  The Finder can give me the name of the file; surely there's a way to get it to do that???  In any case, I have no idea what Cocoa's syntax is and would far rather stick with Applescript if possible.

Comment: Well, same answer. Cast to a string. Now you have a pathname string. Now you can talk to the Finder via Applescript. Anyway my answer does display the pathname of the file, and you have not at all explained how that differs from your desired output.

Comment: Plus, if you didn’t want to talk to Cocoa, why didn’t you just use Script Editor or Script Debugger to write a droplet?

Comment: I've reposted since this thread seems to be closed now.  I hope my new post is more clear.  Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Many, many thanks for this,@matt.  Performance is not an issue since it's only to fill in a field in the UI at launch. I simply wanted to get the Finder to do it because I know nothing about Cocoa but know how to talk to the Finder.

Comment: But you won't be able to drive the Cocoa interface _without_ knowing something about Cocoa. So your reason for using Xcode rather than writing an AppleScript droplet will be void. Your recalcitrance at learning the environment in which you have chosen to operate seems foolishly stubborn and self-defeating. Again, as I've said before, I recommend that you read Shane Stanley's book before any more grass grows under your feet.